# Weak $*$ density of $L^2$ in signed measures

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded domain that is smooth enough, and denote by $\mathcal{M}(\Omega)$ the regular Borel measures. Let $C_0(\Omega)$ be the continuous functions that are $0$ on $\partial \Omega$.

> Prove that $L^2$ is dense in $\mathcal{M}(\Omega)$ in the weak $*$ sense

Here is a sketch, I'm definitely missing some details, but could the following work in principle? If not, do you have any idea on how to prove the claim?

Let $\mu \in C_0(\Omega)^*=\mathcal{M}(\Omega)$, $\mu(\phi) = \int_\Omega \phi d\mu$. One can write $d\mu = \frac{d\mu}{dx} dx$, with $\frac{d\mu}{dx} \in L^1$. Taking $f_n \in L^2$ converging in $L^1$ to $\frac{d\mu}{dx}$, we get $(f_n,\phi)_{L^2}\rightarrow \mu(\phi)$, the desired weak $*$ density result.

Comment: Why should the Radon-Nikodym derivative $d\mu/dx$ exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $L^{2}$ is not dense in $\mathcal M(\Omega)$ then there exists $g \in C(\Omega)$ such that $\int f(x)g(x)dx=0$ for all $f \in L^{2}$ but $g \neq 0$ (because the dual of $(\mathcal M (\Omega),weak*)$ is $C(\Omega)$). Clearly $\int f(x)g(x)dx=0$ for all $f \in L^{2}$ implies $\int_E g(x)dx=0$ for all Borel sets $E \subseteq \Omega$ so $g=0$.